# How do I count the letters in each word of a list of words?

Tags: c

As the code is currently, it outputs:

```
hjk
hg
kjgj
Word 0: 12
Word 1: 0
Word 2: 0
```

When it should be:

```
Word 0: 3
Word 1: 2
Word 2: 4
```

I don't know what I am doing wrong, here is the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define MAX_WORDS_COUNT 10

main()
{
    int wordsLength[MAX_WORDS_COUNT];
    int i, c, inspace = 0, currWord = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < MAX_WORDS_COUNT; i++) 
        wordsLength[i] = 0;

    while ((c = getchar()) != EOF) {
        if (c != ' ' || c != '\t' || c != '\n') {
            wordsLength[currWord]++;
            inspace = 0;
        } else {
            if (inspace == 0)
                currWord++;
            inspace = 1;
        }   
    }

    for(i = 0; i < MAX_WORDS_COUNT; i++)
        printf("Word %d: %d\n", i, wordsLength[i]);


}
```

Comment: Have you tried stepping through your code in a debugger?

Comment: @James whoops, that's what my eyes do when `Should be:` is in the same block as the output.

Comment: You might also want to look at isalpha()

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
    if (c != ' ' || c != '\t' || c != '\n') {
```

You should be using &&. You've got 3 mutually exclusive conditions, and are ORing them, which means ALL conditions satisfy this.

```
    if (c != ' ' && c != '\t' && c != '\n') {
```

will work.

Answer (score 2):

You want `&&` instead of `||` in your condition...otherwise look at the output you posted, it thinks all 12 characters belong to one word.

Change this:  `if (c != ' ' || c != '\t' || c != '\n')`

To:  `if (c != ' ' && c != '\t' && c != '\n')`